# Extrapolate overlapping time periods into the before, overlap and after vin SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, overlapping

I have data that will contain overlapping dates on different rows. For every two rows that contain an overlap I need to break this up appropriately as follows.

First of all, the data looks like the following:

```
EMPID FIRSTNAME SURNAME ACTIVITY  START_DATE          END_DATE            HOURS_PER_DAY STATION
101   ANDREW    SMITH   AVAILABLE 2013-07-08 09:00:00 2013-07-08 17:00:00 8.00             LONDON
101   ANDREW    SMITH   SICKNESS  2013-07-08 07:00:00 2013-07-08 12:00:00 5.00             LONDON
```

The reason for this is the data originally came from two separate tables and I have inserted the contents of both tables into one.

This data will eventually be grouped per person providing a total of the 'Hours Per Day' column. In the above table this person would have 13 hours but as we can see above the timespan of both periods is only 10 hours.

In the above example I need the results to be divided into 3 rows - the bit before the overlap, the overlap and the bit after the overlap:

```
EMPID  NAME ACTIVITY  START_DATE          END_DATE            HOURS_PER_DAY STATION
101   JOHN  SICKNESS  2013-07-08 07:00:00 2013-07-08 09:00:00 2             LONDON
101   JOHN  SICKNESS  2013-07-08 09:00:00 2013-07-08 12:00:00 3             LONDON
101   JOHN  AVAILABLE 2013-07-08 12:00:00 2013-07-08 17:00:00 5             LONDON
```

For time period that overlaps must be classified as Sickness. Please note there are other options other than Available and Sickness, but the only thing that will overlap is Sickness to any other type e.g. a clash between 'Sickness' and 'Available' or a clash between 'Sickness' and 'Training'.

Also, the data has already been divided into 24 hour periods - i.e. I have already extrapolated a sickness period that spans 4 days into 4 different rows which is why the hours per day column will never be more than 24 - if a full 24 hour period is present then the end date will be exactly 1 day after the start date - both the start and end dates will be at midnight. When I have tried to perform what is required I have tried to group the data by EMPID, NAME, CAST(START_DATE) AS DATE, CAST(END_DATE AS DATE) and STATION. These are the appropriate fields that would determine a grouping that needs to be compared.

Please note there are currently approx. 2500 rows of data similar to that provided and the following types of overlaps are possible (if the AVAILABLE entry starts at 09:00 and ends at 17:00 - please note that isn't the case I'm just using that as an example:

- A SICKNESS and AVAILABLE start and end at exactly the same time - e.g. Sickness begins at 09:00 and ends at 17:00 (Results 8 hours SICKNESS)
- A SICKNESS starts before the AVAILABLE entry and ends in the middle of it: e.g. Sickness begins at 07:00 and ends at 12:00 (Results: 2 hours SICKNESS, 3 hours SICKNESS for the overlap, 5 hours AVAILABLE)
- A SICKNESS starts in the middle of an AVAILABLE entry and ends after the AVAILABLE entry, e.g. Sickness begins at 12:00 and ends at 22:00 (Results: 3 hours AVAILABLE, 5 hours SICKNESS for the overlap, 5 hours AVAILABLE)
- A SICKNESS starts during an AVAILABLE entry and ends during an AVAILABLE entry, e.g. Sickness begins at 11:00 and ends at 14:00 (Results: 2 hours AVAILABLE, 3 hours SICKNESS for the overlap, 3 hours AVAILABLE)
- a SICKNESS starts before an AVAILABLE entry and ends after and AVAILABLE entry, e.g. Sickness begins at 06:00 and ends 18:00 (Results: 12 hours sickness)
- A sickness starts midway through the AVAILABLE entry and ends at the same time
- A sickness starts midway through the AVAILABLE entry and ends during an AVAILABLE entry.

Once more please note 'AVAILABLE' isn't the only option.

My query is currently to the point of having the data returned in the format at the top of this post which is stored in a temporary table @INDIVIDUALDAYS - I now want to do whatever is required to @INDIVIDUALDAYS to extrapolate it as describe above.

I'd like the data returned in exactly the same format with the same columns (just extrapolated onto multiple rows as I need to do some further manipulation and calculations on it.

I'm happy to provide my current code if required, but it is over 200 lines long and I believe I've given you enough information

Here is some sample data that covers the 7 different permeations above:

```
101 Andrew  Smith   Available   2014-08-19 09:00:00.000 2014-08-19 17:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   SICKNESS    2014-08-19 09:00:00.000 2014-08-19 17:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   SICKNESS    2014-08-20 12:00:00.000 2014-08-20 19:00:00.000 7.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   Available   2014-08-20 09:00:00.000 2014-08-20 17:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   Available   2014-08-21 09:00:00.000 2014-08-21 17:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   SICKNESS    2014-08-21 04:00:00.000 2014-08-21 12:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   SICKNESS    2014-08-22 06:00:00.000 2014-08-22 18:00:00.000 12.00   London
101 Andrew  Smith   Available   2014-08-22 09:00:00.000 2014-08-22 17:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   Available   2014-08-23 09:00:00.000 2014-08-23 17:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   SICKNESS    2014-08-23 11:00:00.000 2014-08-23 14:00:00.000 3.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   Available   2014-08-24 09:00:00.000 2014-08-23 17:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   SICKNESS    2014-08-24 09:00:00.000 2014-08-23 14:00:00.000 3.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   Available   2014-08-25 09:00:00.000 2014-08-23 17:00:00.000 8.00    London
101 Andrew  Smith   SICKNESS    2014-08-25 11:00:00.000 2014-08-23 17:00:00.000 3.00    London
```

Comment: Shouldn't option 3 above be 
A SICKNESS starts in the middle of an AVAILABLE entry and ends after the AVAILABLE entry, e.g. Sickness begins at 12:00 and ends at 22:00 (Results: 3 hours AVAILABLE, 5 hours SICKNESS for the overlap, 5 hours SICKNESS).  If they are sick, aren't they sick?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, first you need to get both rows combined together as 1 row.  Once you have all the data as a single row, you can do a series of union queries to build the resultant rows, one query for each condition.

This builds the test data:

```
INSERT INTO TData
    ([ID], [FName], [LName], [Status], [StartTime], [EndTime], [Hours], [Location])
VALUES
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'Available', '2014-08-19 09:00:00', '2014-08-19 17:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'SICKNESS', '2014-08-19 09:00:00', '2014-08-19 17:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'SICKNESS', '2014-08-20 12:00:00', '2014-08-20 19:00:00', 7.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'Available', '2014-08-20 09:00:00', '2014-08-20 17:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'Available', '2014-08-21 09:00:00', '2014-08-21 17:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'SICKNESS', '2014-08-21 04:00:00', '2014-08-21 12:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'SICKNESS', '2014-08-22 06:00:00', '2014-08-22 18:00:00', 12.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'Available', '2014-08-22 09:00:00', '2014-08-22 17:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'Available', '2014-08-23 09:00:00', '2014-08-23 17:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'SICKNESS', '2014-08-23 11:00:00', '2014-08-23 14:00:00', 3.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'Available', '2014-08-24 09:00:00', '2014-08-23 17:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'SICKNESS', '2014-08-24 09:00:00', '2014-08-23 14:00:00', 3.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'Available', '2014-08-25 09:00:00', '2014-08-23 17:00:00', 8.00, 'London'),
    (101, 'Andrew', 'Smith', 'SICKNESS', '2014-08-25 11:00:00', '2014-08-23 17:00:00', 3.00, 'London')
;
```

And here is a start on the result.  You need to add more UNION clauses for each row/condition that will finally be displayed.

```
;WITH Combined AS (
SELECT T1.*, t2.StartTime AS S_StartTime, t2.EndTime AS S_EndTime, 
        t2.Status AS S_Status, t2.Hours AS S_Hours
FROM TData T1 --Change TData to your table name
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tdata T2 ON T1.id = T2.id 
        AND CAST(T1.StartTime AS date) = CAST(T2.StartTime as date) 
        AND t1.Status <> t2.Status
WHERE T1.Status <> 'SICKNESS' 
)
--this is case 1 Show sickness only?  If not, add another row
SELECT ID, FName, LName, s_Status AS Status, 
        s_StartTime AS StartTime, s_EndTime AS EndTime, 
        S_Hours AS Hours, Location
FROM combined 
WHERE StartTime = S_StartTime and EndTime = s_EndTime 
UNION --Case 2 Row 1
SELECT ID, FName, LName, s_Status AS Status, 
        s_StartTime AS StartTime, StartTime AS EndTime, 
        DATEDIFF(minute,S_StartTime,StartTime)/60 AS Hours, Location
FROM combined 
WHERE S_StartTime < StartTime 
      AND S_EndTime BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime 
UNION --case 2 row 2
SELECT ID, FName, LName, S_Status AS Status, 
       StartTime AS StartTime, S_EndTime AS EndTime, 
       DATEDIFF(minute,StartTime,S_EndTime)/60 AS Hours, Location
FROM combined 
WHERE S_StartTime < StartTime 
      AND S_EndTime BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime 
UNION --case 2 row 3
SELECT ID, FName, LName, Status, 
       S_EndTime AS StartTime, EndTime AS EndTime, 
       DATEDIFF(minute,S_EndTime,EndTime)/60 AS Hours, Location
FROM combined 
WHERE S_StartTime < StartTime 
      AND S_EndTime BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime
```

I can work out the rest of the clauses, but it should be fairly clear how to do it.  Let me know if you need additional help.